# Textarea that a user can use for formatting their imput text

Tags: formatting

I am creating a custom object, where  a user needs to input a large amount of text. Is it possible to allow formatting of the text, i.e. display a list button, a bold and italics button etc?
Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible if the field type is - Text Area (Rich).